# Why do you need to use 12m, 7m and total power data in interferometry

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, interference, interferometry

In my understanding in an interferometer, i.e. ALMA, the 12m, 7m and Total Power (TP) telescopes look at the same frequency channels and the same object. However the 12m telescope looks in much finer detail, seeing gas and dust. 7m telescopes look at the emission from bigger objects like stars. So my question is why do you need the total power data. What does it add if you look at both the small and large scales without it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure not all interferometry works with a 12m and a 7m telescope. Can you be more specific what setup you are looking at and what exactly is confusing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key is (my emphasis, from [ALMA observatory site](http://almaobservatory.org/en/press-room/announcements-events/1154-aca-total-power-array-spectrometer-pdr-))

> [...]a group of antennas called Total Power (TP) Array, *specially designed for precise measurement of the intensity* of radio waves coming from target objects.

This has to do with angular resolution - if you don't sample sufficiently, you may not know the total power. I deduce this from the following answer to the question "[For ACA observations, may I decline the Total Power observations in order to reduce the total time of my proposal?](https://help.almascience.org/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/228/1/for-aca-observations-may-i-decline-the-total-power-observations-in-order-to-reduce-the-total-time-of-my-proposal)":

> The OT automatically computes whether or not 7-m Array and Total Power (TP) observations are necessary based on the 'Largest Angular Structure in source' (LAS) entry in the Control & Performance editor. If the requested LAS is larger than that achievable by the ACA 7-m array alone, Total Power (TP) observations will be added if possible (in Cycle 4 this is the case for spectral line observations in Bands 3-8; for continuum and high-frequency observations the TP array is not currently offered). Users may not reject the scheduling of TP observations because they have access to single dish data from other telescopes. The rationale behind this is that the ALMA archive should provide the best and most complete dataset possible to future archival researchers, including TP data when needed.